# LEFT JOIN on mysql query do not get results like i want

Tags: mysql, left-join

i have 2 table , awards and awards_user  , and have problem with LEFT JOIN on mysql query do not get results like i want

awards :

```
awardid  | name   | link  
1        | award1 | photo link    
2        | award2 | photo link   
3        | award3 | photo link   
4        | award4 | photo link
```

awards_user :

```
awardid  | username
2        | mark      
2        | jon
3        | mark    
1        | jon
```

I try to get results like that :

```
award name  |  award photo  |  Users
award1      |      link     |  jon
award2      |      link     |  mark,jon
award3      |      link     |  mark
award4      |      link     |  -------
```

that is my try :

```
 SELECT au.username 
      , au.userid 
      , a.link 
      , a.name 
      , a.awardid 
   FROM awards a
   LEFT 
   JOIN awards_user au
     ON au.awardid = a.awardid
  WHERE a.forumid = 22
  GROUP 
     BY a.awardid 
      , au.username
  ORDER 
     BY a.awardid DESC
```

the Solve the problem:

```
$all_awards = $db->query_read(" SELECT awards.name as name, awards.link as link, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.username) AS username
   FROM awards LEFT JOIN awards_user ON (awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid)
   where awards.forumid = '".$_REQUEST['forumid']."'
   GROUP BY awards.awardid, awards.name, awards.link
  ");
```

Comment: If you want a result like `award name  |  award photo  |  Users`, don't you think it might be an idea to SELECT *those* columns?

Comment: i don't understand you , i must use `left join` , becouse there users have more on of awards

Comment: That's not how we roll

Comment: Do not place `$_REQUEST['forumid']` into SQL query strings. Otherwise I'll CV against this: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/367456) - Also your question is not clear. You want something, however you didn't share what you get instead and what your understanding of the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` does exactly what you need:

```
SELECT
       a.name AS name
     , a.link AS photo
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT au.username) AS users
FROM awards AS a
     LEFT JOIN awards_user AS au ON (au.awardid = a.awardid)
GROUP BY
       a.awardid
     , a.name
     , a.link
ORDER BY
     a.awardid DESC
```

More info about `MySQL GROUP_CONCAT` here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

BTW, you can even sort usernames or choose different separator if you want in group_concat. Just read MySQL manual and *google* "mysql group_concat examples" :)

Comment: okay i try it , but same problem when i get username of users , only show 1 user , i want show all user Who got same award `(jon,mark,elc ..)`

Comment: sorry , it's worked , but i have now new problem ... i want put userid on every user

Comment: I don't see user_id field in your sample data. Anyway you can do that by adding one more group_concat. On the other hand - are you sure what you're doing exactly? What's the point to get usernames and ids as CSV?

Comment: i want get all awards and what users Holders of each, anyway i found the The correct answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

and also add `` on table names because your naming conventions are pretty rough might match with mysql reserved words and again **PRACTISE SECURITY FILTER YOUR INPUTS** `$_REQUEST['forumid']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT awards.name as award_name, award.link as award_photo, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.username AS users
   FROM awards LEFT JOIN awards_user ON (awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid)
   GROUP BY awards.awardid, awards.name, awards.link;
```

Comment: Oops, @DarkSide beat me to it while I was typing -- and his looks great.

Comment: and you forgot closing brackets after group_concat :)

Comment: i fix some Mistakes but still show me error `$all_awards = $db->query_read(" SELECT awards.name as name, awards.link as link, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.username AS username)
   FROM awards LEFT JOIN awards_user ON (awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid)
   GROUP BY awards.awardid, awards.name, awards.link
  ");`

Comment: okay i fix the error and i think working good [forgot closing brackets after group_concat]  `$all_awards = $db->query_read(" SELECT awards.name as name, awards.link as link, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards_user.username) AS username
   FROM awards LEFT JOIN awards_user ON (awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid)
   where awards.forumid = '".$_REQUEST['forumid']."'
   GROUP BY awards.awardid, awards.name, awards.link
  ");`